# Dynamically creating tabs that contain two tables each

Tags: c#, wpf, list, tabs, datatables

I tend to not be the best at describing things, so I [am including this picture of my "Goal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK6L2.jpg) to clear things up.

Goal: Dynamically create tabs displaying a person's two datasets. The tabs that are created are based on what is typed in.(I have no issue retrieving this data)

I have a datastructure that contains two information sets for an unspecified amount of groups"people". I can currently pull these two datasets(and am freely able to modify them such that it can be set up as a two lists per table(think two columns in excel of paired data). I currently have this as a pair of lists containing strings, but also can receive it as a pair of lists containing doubles, as a dictionary, or basically anything as long as it allows me to accomplish this goal.

I don't know how to dynamically create tabs in C# with WPF nor how to display lists/tables within these tabs. I can do it for a single tab using the editor, but since the "person" is chosen by the user in runtime, hardcoding the tabs isn't an option.

Comment: Take a look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460655/load-usercontrol-in-tabitem-programatically/38461302#38461302